# Removing Left recursion in CFG's

Tags: context-free-grammar, left-recursion

How would I go about removing left recursion from this line from a grammar?

A -> D | R | r B A n ; | AA | epsilon

r, n and ; are terminal symbols. D,R,B and A are all non-terminals.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer [in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion).

Also, this is a possible duplicate of [removing left recursion in a context free grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826852/removing-left-recursion-in-a-context-free-grammar).